# SSRS Lookup function failing on source name

Tags: sql-server, wcf, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, lookup

I am using SSRS in VS 2012. My report solution has a WCF service as a shared DataSource, and a shared DataSet using that DataSource, for which the query works. It has a parameter 'StudentID', and when run on it's own returns student data as expected. One of the fields returned in as integer called SSIS. My report has a lookup that should query the student DataSource on the StudentID and return the SSIS. However, my lookup function errors out, but I can't see why. Here is the function:

```
=Lookup(Fields!StudentID.Value, Fields!StudentID.Value, Fields!SSID.Value, "StudentDetails")
```

The error on preview is: The definition of the report is invalid. The Value expression for the text box (where the function is) has a scope parameter that is not valid for a lookup function. The scope parameter must be set to a string constant that is the name of a dataset.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Well, for one thing you've got Fields!SSID.Value but you say the field name is SSIS, so that needs sorting.

Other than that, the only time I've seen that error message is when the fourth parameter (I.E. "StudentDetails") doesn't exactly match the name of a dataset - this is case sensitive so I would double check that you've got them identical in that regard.

Comment: Acronym mix up, sorry. I do have the correct acronym and the Dataset is spelled and cased the same as the shared dataset StudentDetails. The function's expression has the squiggly line under the name of the dataset, as if it is incorrect.